# Create arbitrary Java class at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

Does anyone know of any Java libraries that would allow me to define a new Java class at runtime and also instantiate an instance of that class?

Comment: What would be the purpose of creating a class at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is an all purpose Java bytecode manipulation and analysis framework. It can be used to modify existing classes or dynamically generate classes, directly in binary form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're looking for but consider [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) library.

> Javassist (Java Programming Assistant) makes Java bytecode manipulation simple. It is a class library for editing bytecodes in Java; it enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file when the JVM loads it. [...]
>
> cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation Library, It is used to extend JAVA classes and implements interfaces at runtime. [...]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work at bytecode level, a possible solution is to use the [Compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) of Java SE 6. See [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/12/invoke-javac-at-runtime/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class can be used to create dynamic classes that implement specific interfaces at runtime. Such classes use an [InvocationHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) to handle method calls.